# QT : how to synchronize QtableViews in layouts?

Tags: c++, qt, qt5

i'm working on a Qt project with an interface and i'm using four QTableViews and for some reason, the last one is not following the others when i stretch the windows. the 4 tableviews have the exact same parameters. they are in layouts, along with other items on the interface. i set the MaximumWidth of my tableview like this :

```
int hHeaderWidth = ui->tableCSB_Right->verticalHeader()->width();
int rowWidth = ui->tableErr_Right->columnWidth(0);
int tableWidth = (nbOfAnt/2)*rowWidth + hHeaderWidth;

ui->tableErr_Right->setMaximumWidth(tableWidth);
ui->tableErr_left->setMaximumWidth(tableWidth);
ui->tableCSB_Right->setMaximumWidth(tableWidth);
ui->tableCSB_Left->setMaximumWidth(tableWidth);
ui->tableLeft_Coupling->setMaximumWidth(tableWidth);
ui->tableRight_Coupling->setMaximumWidth(tableWidth);
```

and here's what i get when i launch my program and when i stretch the window:
[image: here]

as you can see the last qtableview goes way farther and the other ones along with its QPushButton and labels. i dont get why does it behave like this. has anyone dealt with this problem ?

thank you in advance